# sched.h different/missing in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

`/usr/include/sched.h` in cygwin looks completely different from say RedHat/SLES distributions

`/usr/include/bits/sched.h` is missing altogether.

Am I missing something obvious or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Different system may have different header implementation 
None of the cygwin header are exact equal to the linux one,
most are similar to BSD ones.

For reference on sched.h

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sched.h.html